# How to log in when only available database is taken offline

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication

I have a SQL Server 2008 database on shared hosting, and stupidly clicked on "Take Offline" in Management Studio.

Now, when I'm trying to log in, it says that default database is unavailable, and login fails. I do not have access to any other available databases on that account.

Is there any way to make my database back online?

Comment: Yes, call the hosting provider. Open a support ticket. They will correct your mistake. However I suggest you be very careful when pointing and clicking in the UI. There are things they won't be able to correct easily (such as right-clicking a table and clicking "Delete").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can bring your database back online. Just call the hosting provider and open a support ticket; they will correct your mistake.

I converted my comment to an answer. Since, in a hosted scenario, the originally accepted answer (now deleted) actually wasn't appropriate. For those that can still read it, I suggest not trying to hack your way into your hosting provider's master database - if they're worth their salt, they are probably auditing that activity and it may violate your terms of use. Besides, your user account is extremely unlikely to hold the permissions necessary to run `ALTER DATABASE` from *any* database you can connect to. Just do it the right way and call them - they have a support department for exactly this reason.

In the future, however, I suggest you be very careful when pointing and clicking in the UI. There are things they won't be able to correct easily (such as right-clicking a table and clicking "Delete").